# Get Hometown information from members group

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to use Graph **API** to get Hometown information from members of a specific group.
How can I do it?
I am retrieving Name without problem but not the other fields.

On graph explorer I try this string :

```
GET GROUP-ID-NUMBER/members?fields=name
```

But if I use this string, I get only Administrator,ID, Name Field

```
GET GROUP-ID-NUMBER/members?
```

I want to make group statistics and I want to known also members hometown.

Answer (score 0):

To get more information members of the group must authorize your app with correct permissions for Hometown. You must also be a member of the same group for that purpose. so you need to have an app and you will get only those members correct information who will authorize your app.